Is the resistor between the clock and the NPN needed?
I have a circuit that uses an NPN transistor inverter to invert a clock signal. The circuit calls for two resistors, a pull up and one in between the input signal. Virtually all of the circuits found use these two resistors. These sites did not explain the purpose of R1, they just said to use one.
Do I actually need the resistor in between the clock input and NPN? If I do, what is the purpose of this resistor?
The circuit in question:


I add the ratio Rb:Rc should be about 10 (not a 1). And don’t expect this inverter will work at 14MHz.

Output is a poor name for an inverted CLK. Do you actually need the transistor.  What is Output connected to?

@StainlessSteelRat the inverted signal will be used in a clock divider circuit. Yes I could use an inverter IC, but if I only need one, it seems very wasteful to use one of six on the chip. I am aware of the single inverter chips, but they are SMD and I am abysmal at SMD soldering.

Yikes, I don’t think your inverted 14MHz clock is going to look quite as you expect on the output. You should look at it on an oscilloscope to see if it’ll meet your needs. I would suggest using an actual 7400 series logic inverter. Either 74HC or 74LVC series should be good enough and cost effective. Maybe 74HC1G04 or 74LVC1G04?? Usually RTL logic inverters made out of BJTs or FETs are only used for slow signals like button presses and stuff like that, not clocks.

Is the non-inverted clock used anywhere else in the same circuit? If so, why does the output need to be inverted?

@StarCat it is the undivided frequency stage of the frequency divider, as shown here: Frequency Divider - Wikipedia

@SteKulov would the SN74HC05N work as well?

@ZackeryFleming  It might.  Your rising edge is going to be limited by the choice of pullup resistor.  You'll have to try different ones considering the absolute maximum current ratings in the datasheet.

@SteKulov looking at the datasheet, I have three possible values for the maximum output current output clamp current, continuous output current, or continuous output current through VCC/GND.

Yes, that’s correct.

@SteKulov which one should I use? They are all different values.

They are all important. Anything that states “clamp current” means when voltages presented to the pins exceed VCC or GND. You usually have to worry about that only if your pullup resistor goes to a different supply rail than the chip. The continuous output current is the main thing to look at. The last one means that you have 6 outputs and you can’t pull max continuous from all 6 because the chip as a whole has a limit. You didn’t state your supply voltage but if it’s 5V I would probably start at 470ohm and then if it looks bad on the scope try 390, 330, 270 and see which is acceptable.

@ZackeryFleming See my comments under Matt's answer to see a simulation I ran.

R1 has two purposes.

Without R1 current flowing from clock generator output to transistor base to emitter to ground will be limited only by clock generator itself. But even if it's not a short circuit (or is it?), the transistor needs only small base current to work, so it should be okay to add some extra limit anyway.

Without R1 the voltage at generator output will drop down to 0.7v approx. (forward voltage drop by base-emitter diode junction). Then other clock consumers (the clock signal is usually shared between many chips, right?) will stop working correctly.


Also note that resistors R1 and R2 affect clock's rising and falling times seen at OUTPUT-bar. So if the generated clock gets too fast you may need to decrease resistor values and/or replace the transistor.

Won’t R1 also greatly influence the switching speed? We are talking about a clock signal after all…

@SteKulov Good point.

@SteKulov that depends a lot on the capacity of the base-emitter stretch of the transistor. If the schematic is true, it's up to 14MHz. Nothing to sneeze at but not crazy fast. If speed is an issue a voltage divider from Vcc to GND on the base of the Transistor might help.

@kruemi Good call on the divider.  I couldn't get the Vcc to GND divider working, but dividing the base out from the oscillator seems to help with the duty cycle.  It's going to be up to the questioner if the slow edge rates and/or duty cycle matters for their application.

R1 limits the current through the Q1 base-emitter junction to a value that is safe both for the transistor and for the oscillator output stage.  Like most diodes, a transistor base-emitter junction has no inherent current limiting.  If you connected it across a car battery, it would happily destroy itself trying to conduct 600 A.
The oscillator datasheet has a typical peak output voltage and a maximum recommended output current.  Using Ohm's Law, R1 can be calculated to keep this current safely below the max value.

The short answer is yes, you need the resistor. However as noted in comments, this circuit won't really work over the range 1-14MHz, in fact it barely works at 1MHz:

